How to use the AddBandPassMaskToImage() method?
I am trying to apply a band pass filter to an image using dm script to filter out the noisy pixels. Can I achieve this task using the AddBandPassMaskToImage() method? It only works with the RealImage datatype and the filtered image that it's returning has a large black circular band in the middle. How do I use it correctly?
AddBandPassMaskToImage( ImageReference mask, Number x_center, Number y_center, Number
band_radius_1, Number band_radius_2, Number filter_length, Boolean do_inverse )

My code and images of the results are given below. I wasn't expecting any black bands as shown in the filtered image. I suspect that I am using the method incorrectly, but since the mask applies to     RealImage data type and not ComplexImage data type, I assumed that I wouldn't need to do any operations on the FFT.
image front = GetFrontImage()
number xsize, ysize, zsize
get3dsize(front, xsize, ysize, zsize)
image frontCopy := front
AddBandPassMaskToImage(frontCopy, xsize/2, ysize/2, 5, 154, 1, 0)
showImage(frontCopy)

I don't have the reputation to post images but the links are given below:
Before applying the method

After applying the method


what language, what libraries?

such filtering is done in the frequency domain, i.e. you are supposed apply the filter to the FFT, not the image itself.

@ChristophRackwitz It's the custom scripting language of an application called DigitalMicrograph - that's what the [dm-script] tag is for.

In general I would advise using the Filter Palette to set up (named) filters  and then using them with the IFMApplyFilter command, as it is also described in the Filtering section of the script-examples in the F1 help documentation:

The command AddBandPassMaskToImage is just adding smooth donut-shaped zero-to-one valued sections to an image, to help creating band-pass masks in FourierSpace. The mask then needs to be applied (multiplied) to  attenuate the intensity before back-transforming the image into real space.
realimage img := RealImage( "Test Image 2D", 4, 512, 512 )
img = abs( itheta*2*icol/(iwidth+1)* sin(iTheta*20)  ) 
img = PoissonRandom(100*img)
img.ShowImage()

// Transform
compleximage img_FFT := FFT(img)

// Modify in F-Space
// Build mask
image mask:=RealImage("Mask in F-Space",4,512,512)
mask.AddBandPassMaskToImage( 256, 256, 200, 40, 10, 0 )
mask.ShowImage()

//Apply mask
img_FFT *= mask
img_FFT.SetName( "Masked FFT" )
img_FFT.ShowImage()

// Transform back
image img_filter := modulus(iFFT(img_FFT))
img_filter.SetName("Filtered")
img_filter.ShowImage() 

EGUPerformActionWithAllShownImages("arrange")


